# How to print all lines in textfile in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print each line of text from a textfile in a certain format but it only prints the very last line instead of all the lines.
The textfile I am using has 4 lines but depending on the user it may have less or more.

My code:

```
def loadrecipefile (recipe_file):
    infile=open(recipe_file)
    Linelist=infile.readlines()
    global cookbook
    for line in Linelist:
        wordList=line.split()
        r1={'apple':int(wordList[1]),'beets':int(wordList[2]),'carrots':int(wordList[3])}
        cookbook={wordList[0]:r1}

def printrecipes():
    for name,ingred in cookbook.items():
        print(name + " " + str(ingred['apple']) + " " + str(ingred['beets']) + " " + str(ingred['carrots']))
```

So the input would be (in my case):

```
loadrecipefile("recipe_file.txt")

printrecipes()
```

then it would print each line of the textfile which I want it to look like:

```
Recipe1 1 4 3

Recipe2 0 2 4

Recipe3 3 0 1

Recipe4 2 1 0
```

but I only get the last line: `Recipe4 2 1 0`

I'm not sure how to go about of this since the loadrecipefile seems to work fine jsut the printrecipes is not printing what I want it to

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the contents of the `cookbook` variable in each loop:

```
cookbook={wordList[0]:r1}
```

This is executed N times, creating a new dictionary with one key/value in it every time.

You should instead add to the existing dictionary in each loop:

```
cookbook = {}

for ...:
    cookbook[wordList[0]] = r1
```

---

Now, the part you did not ask, but you should fix because it looks terrible: don't use global variables. When? You will not be wrong if you never use them.

Instead of storing the results in a global variable, return the result from the function:

```
def loadrecipefile(recipe_file):

    ...

    return cookbook
```

Then, in the other function, take the result:

```
    def printrecipes(recipefile):
        cookbook = loadrecipefile(recipefile)
        for name, ingred in cookbook.items():
            ...
```

Or do this:

```
    def printrecipes(cookbook):
        for name, ingred in cookbook.items():
            ...
```

and then:

```
cookbook = loadrecipefile(recipe_file)
printrecipes(cookbook)
```

Comment: but I tried doing that and it said that for printrecipes() recipefile isn't defined so how would I use the loadrecipefile in printrecipes?

Comment: @TaitmiLee Well, in that case, `printrecipes` also has to take `recipefile` as argument. I modified the answer.

Comment: @TaitmiLee The next step to make it even better would be to create a `Cookbok` class with methods `load_from_file` and `print_recipes`, both using a member variable for the data currently in `cookbook`.